# Angularjs: nested ng-repeat with key reference from one to the another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want reference the key value from one repeat value to the other.  Its a bit hard to explain but here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u75us/163/

I want to get the f_column value from key_var array and get that same keyvalue from value_var array.

**The jsfiddle code will actually give error** because its not valid **{{val.{{key.f_column}}}}** in angularjs.. Thats only pseudocode that I want to achieve.

How I can achieve this?

```
<ul ng:controller="Cntl">
<li ng:repeat="key in key_var">{{key.f_column}}
    <li ng:repeat="val in value_var">{{val.{{key.f_column}}}</li>
</li>
```

```
function Cntl() {
this.value_var = [ 
    {"v_a":"a" , "column1" : "v1" },
    {"v_a":"a" , "column2" : "v2" } 
]

this.key_var =  [
     {"f_column":"column2"},
    {"f_column":"column1"}
];
```

}

Comment: try `{{val[key.f_column]}}`. That said, you're using a really old angular version, and your html nesting is wrong.

Comment: @Yoshi It doesn't seems to work :S . I changed to more latest angular js http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/1815/

Comment: you have an extra dot there `{{val.[key.f_column]}}` change it to `{{val[key.f_column]}}`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/fHCAb/

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks but it still does't work :S  http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/1817/

Comment: should not i see "v1" and "v2"  in the display ??

Comment: As I wrote above, your html nesting is wrong (`li` in `li`) use anything else, and it will be visible. E.g. `<div ng:repeat="val in value_var">{{val[key.f_column]}}</div>`. demo: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/1818/

Comment: @Yoshi Ohh.. sorry that i didn't pay much attention to wrong html. It works now Thanks alot. U can post it as anwer i'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reference a property of an object using a variable use the square bracket notation. This goes for javascript in general and for angular as well.

E.g.:

```
{{val[key.f_column]}}
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/OsuKUQo/1/

Answer (score 0):

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; ??

```
{{val.{{key.f_column}}}
```

change

```
{{ val.key.f_column }}
```

Comment: This will not work because `val` has no property called `key`. (only `v_a` and `column1` or `column2`)

Comment: Have you tested the code? it doesn't seems to work either. can u try and test in this fiddle ? http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/1815/  Thank You

Answer (score 0):

As Yoshi said above, you can access a JavaScript property using `[]` notation.

In your example another fundamental references were missing: `$scope` in your controller and `ng-app` in your html. Without them AngularJS cannot bind your app to your html; to know what `value_var` and `key_var` are all about they must be bound to `$scope`.

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/1820/